# Using Regex Array with String Array

Tags: c#, arrays, regex

I'm trying to make a program where a user can input an array of serial numbers and have each corresponding product show up.

Suppose I know that Product A always starts with "C02", Product B always ends in "X02", and Product C always contains "A1700". Then if the user input was "C02HGV32,N93XA1700D,J3429X02", it would return "C02HGV32: Product A; N93XA1700D: Product C; J3429X02: Product B".

How would I get an array of Regex expressions to compare against the array of strings? Here's what I have:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public class ReturnProduct{
    public Regex[] compareAgainst = new Regex[3]{@"[C02]*",@"*[X02]",@"*[A1700]*"}; //Clearly not the right way, but not sure how else to do it
```

...

```
public string getTheProduct(string input){
string[] compareString = input.Split(",");
for (int a = 0; a < compareString.Length; a++){
    for (int b = 0; b < compareAgainst.Length; b++){
        //Do something Regex-y with compareString[a] and compareAgainst[b]
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for the correct Regex syntax? Or how to check if a string matches a regex?

Comment: I'm asking both the correct syntax for a Regex array, and how to check each string value against each Regex array value - sorry about the clarity.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but "How exactly would this work?" is not exactly a clear question. I wouldn't assume that you were downvoted for "trying to explain as much as possible".

Comment: I guess I should have used a semicolon for that - the "How exactly would this work?" was relating to the previous sentence. Bad English. I've updated it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the requirements of these codes are so simple you can use `String.Contains`, `String.StartsWith` and `String.EndsWith`. You can create a `Dictionary` to hold product names and functions to check if a given string has the pattern for a product.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Predicate<string>>
{
    ["Product A"] = s => s.StartsWith("C02"),
    ["Product B"] = s => s.EndsWith("X02"),
    ["Product C"] = s => s.Contains("A1700")
};

string GetProductName(string serialNum)
{
    foreach(var keyVal in dict)
    {
        if(keyVal.Value(serialNum))
            return keyVal.Key;
    }

    return "No product name found";
}

List<(string, string)> GetProductNames(string str)
{
    var productCodes = str.Split(',');
    var productNames = new List<(string, string)>(); // list of tuples (string, string)

    foreach(var serialNum in productCodes)
    {
        productNames.Add((serialNum, GetProductName(serialNum)));
    }

    return productNames;
}
```

Usage:

```
var userString = "C02HGV32,N93XA1700D,J3429X02";
List<(string serialNum, string name)> productNames = GetProductNames(userString);
foreach(var tuple in productNames)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{tuple.serialNum} : {tuple.name}");
}
```

---

If you specifically want to use Regex, you can use the following patterns:

```
var regexDict = new Dictionary<string, Regex>
{
    ["Product A"] = new Regex("^C02"), //'^' means beginning of string
    ["Product B"] = new Regex("X02$"), //'$' means end of string
    ["Product C"] = new Regex("A1700") //given string anywhere
};

string GetProductName(string serialNum)
{
    foreach(var keyVal in regexDict)
    {
        if(keyVal.Value.IsMatch(serialNum))
            return keyVal.Key;
    }

    return "No product name found";
}

List<(string, string)> GetProductNames(string str)
{
    var productCodes = str.Split(',');
    var productNames = new List<string>();

    foreach(var serialNum in productCodes)
    {
        productNames.Add((serialNum, GetProductName(serialNum)));
    }

    return productNames;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Though with ~2600 products, I was kinda hoping Dictionaries wouldn't have to be used. :/

Comment: Dictionaries are pretty fast, they use hashing internally, but I don't know if your concern is speed or memory usage

Comment: I was planning on having a string array of product names and the Regex array of serial number searches being in the same order, so if the input matched [n] of the Regex array it'd simply return [n] of the string array. I had guessed that would have been by far the fastest since I thought simply accessing the array would have been O(1). I also figured that'd be the least memory.

Comment: You would still have to iterate over the array, and iterating over the dictionary isn't much more work for the program. You'd only stop when you find the product or not find anything so that is the same. Also dictionary uses a couple of arrays to hold the items (and is dinamically resizable) so the memory used isn't much bigger than if you had an array

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Define a class for your products:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Regex Expr { get; set; }
}
```

then create an array with all your regexes:

```
var regexes = new[]
{
    new Product
    {
        Name = "Product A",
        Expr = new Regex("^C02")
    },
    new Product
    {
        Name = "Product B",
        Expr = new Regex("X02$")
    },
    new Product
    {
        Name = "Product C",
        Expr = new Regex("A1700")
    }
};
```

now you can use `LINQ` query:

```
var input = "C02HGV32,N93XA1700D,J3429X02";
var result = string.Join("; ",
    input.Split(',')
    .Select(s => new {regexes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Expr.IsMatch(s))?.Name, Value = s})
    .Select(x => $"{x.Value}: {x.Name}"));
```

`result` would be

> C02HGV32: Product A; N93XA1700D: Product C; J3429X02: Product B

Answer (score 0):

Regex syntax:

- "^C02.*" - Starts with C02 followed by any number of characters including 0 characters.
- "^.*X02" - Starts with any number of characters including 0 characters and ends with X02.
- "^.*A1700.**" - Starts and ends with any number of characters, and contains A1700 somewhere.

  ```
  public static void GetTheProduct(string input, List<Regex> regList)
  {
      List<string> compareString = input.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToList();
      foreach (string item in compareString)
      {
          if (regList[0].Match(item).Success)
              Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", item, "Product A");
          else if (regList[1].Match(item).Success)
              Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", item, "Product B");
          else if (regList[2].Match(item).Success)
              Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", item, "Product C");
      }
  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      List<Regex> regexList = new List<Regex>() { new Regex("^C02.*"), new Regex("^.*X02"), new Regex("^.*A1700.*") };
      GetTheProduct("C02HGV32,N93XA1700D,J3429X02", regexList);
      Console.ReadLine();
  }
  ```

You could also generalize the method and avoid hardcoding Product names.
Like so:

```
    public static void GetTheProduct(string input, Dictionary<string, Regex> regDictionary)
    {
        List<string> compareString = input.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToList();
        foreach (string item in compareString)
        {
            string key = regDictionary.First(x => x.Value.IsMatch(item)).Key;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", item, key);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, Regex> regDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Regex>();
        regDictionary.Add("Product A", new Regex("^C02.*"));
        regDictionary.Add("Product B", new Regex("^.*X02"));
        regDictionary.Add("Product C", new Regex("^.*A1700.*"));

        GetTheProduct("C02HGV32,N93XA1700D,J3429X02", regDictionary);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Note that `^.*X02` doesn't mean ends with anything. No reason to overkill the match as Regex searches for a match inside the string by default: `A1700` is sufficient for contains "A1700". `^C02` is sufficient for begins with "C02".